# Passing data between scenes Errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a game manager making sure my data gets passed on from the first scene on to the next scene. Within the game manager, I have added certain scripts to ensure it gets passed. As you can see in the picture underneath.

[image: Game Manager]

The problem is that the score adds up at the first level, let's say I have 5 points. I go to level 2 and the UI shows my score as 0 (even tho I have nothing put as text within the score text) I kill 1 monster and the UI shows 6. So how can I put the UI to be showing it at all times? (Constant refresh?)

The second problem is that while the score manager does work. The health script cancels everything out when switching levels. 
The user starts with 10 health. Takes damage in the first scene, but in the second scene, the user still has 10 health for some reason?

Game Manager

```
﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public ActionButton PopupPrefab;
    private ActionButton currentlySpawnedPopup;

    public static GameManager instance = null;

    void Awake () {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;
        } else if (instance != this) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }

        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
    }

    void Update () {
        //if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R)) {
        //  RestartScene ();
        //}
    }

    public void InvokeRestartScene (float time) {
        Invoke ("RestartScene", time);
    }   

    public void RestartScene () {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (0);
    }

    public void SpawnPopup (Vector2 position) {
        DespawnPopup ();

        currentlySpawnedPopup = Instantiate (PopupPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity) as ActionButton;
    }

    public void DespawnPopup () {
        if (currentlySpawnedPopup != null) {
            currentlySpawnedPopup.DestroySelf();
            currentlySpawnedPopup = null;
        }
    }

    public void FadePopup () {
        if (currentlySpawnedPopup != null) {
            currentlySpawnedPopup.FadeMe ();
            currentlySpawnedPopup = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Score Manager

```
﻿using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ScoreManager Instance { get; private set; }

    public int Score { get; private set; }

    public int HighScore { get; private set; }

    public bool HasNewHighScore { get; private set; }

    public static event Action<int> ScoreUpdated = delegate {};
    public static event Action<int> HighscoreUpdated = delegate {};

    private const string HIGHSCORE = "HIGHSCORE";
    // key name to store high score in PlayerPrefs

    void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            Instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        // Initialize score
        Score = 0;

        // Initialize highscore
        HighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(HIGHSCORE, 0);
        HasNewHighScore = false;
    }

    public void AddScore(int amount)
    {
        Score += amount;

        // Fire event
        ScoreUpdated(Score);

        if (Score > HighScore)
        {
            UpdateHighScore(Score);
            HasNewHighScore = true;
        }
        else
        {
            HasNewHighScore = false;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateHighScore(int newHighScore)
    {
        // Update highscore if player has made a new one
        if (newHighScore > HighScore)
        {
            HighScore = newHighScore;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(HIGHSCORE, HighScore);
            HighscoreUpdated(HighScore);
        }
    }
}
```

Health Script

```
﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityEvent OnTakeDamageEvent;
    public UnityEvent OnTakeHealEvent;
    public UnityEvent OnDeathEvent;

    [Header ("Max/Starting Health")]
    public int maxHealth;
    [Header ("Current Health")]
    public int health;

    [Header ("IsDeathOrNot")]
    public bool dead = false;

    [Header ("Invincible")]
    public bool invincible = false;
    public bool becomeInvincibleOnHit = false;
    public float invincibleTimeOnHit = 1f;
    private float invincibleTimer = 0f;

    [Header ("Perform Dead Events after x time")]
    public float DieEventsAfterTime = 1f;

    void Start () {
        health = maxHealth;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (invincibleTimer > 0f) {
            invincibleTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

            if (invincibleTimer <= 0f) {
                if (invincible)
                    invincible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool TakeDamage (int amount) {
        if (dead || invincible)
            return false;

        health = Mathf.Max (0, health - amount);

        if (OnTakeDamageEvent != null)
            OnTakeDamageEvent.Invoke();

        if (health <= 0) {
            Die ();
        } else {
            if (becomeInvincibleOnHit) {
                invincible = true;
                invincibleTimer = invincibleTimeOnHit;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool TakeHeal (int amount) {
        if (dead || health == maxHealth)
            return false;

        health = Mathf.Min (maxHealth, health + amount);

        if (OnTakeHealEvent != null)
            OnTakeHealEvent.Invoke();


        return true;
    }

    public void Die () {
        dead = true;

        if (CameraShaker.instance != null) {
            CameraShaker.instance.InitShake(0.2f, 1f);
        }

        StartCoroutine (DeathEventsRoutine (DieEventsAfterTime));
    }

    IEnumerator DeathEventsRoutine (float time) {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (time);
        if (OnDeathEvent != null)
            OnDeathEvent.Invoke();
    }

    public void SetUIHealthBar () {
        if (UIHeartsHealthBar.instance != null) {
            UIHeartsHealthBar.instance.SetHearts (health);
        }
    }
}
```

I have thought of adding the following script on to my Health Script
But then I get the following error messages:

" Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'"

"The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer"

```
    void Awake()
    {
        if (health)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            (int)health = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that the score adds up at the first level, let's say I have 5 points. I go to level 2 and the UI shows my score as 0 (even tho I have nothing put as text within the score text) I kill 1 monster and the UI shows 6. So how can I put the UI to be showing it at all times? (Constant refresh?)

You can make one of the scripts set the UI text score when the scene is loaded.

```
void Start(){
    // Loads the scoreText on start
    scoreText.text = yourCurrentScore.ToString();
    // Will work unless it has a "DontDestroyOnLoad" applied to it
}
```

> The second problem is that while the score manager does work. The
>   health script cancels everything out when switching levels. The user
>   starts with 10 health. Takes damage in the first scene, but in the
>   second scene, the user still has 10 health for some reason?

In your health script, you had this:

```
void Start () {
    health = maxHealth;
}
```

This resets your health everytime the scene loads and starts (Aka when you load to the next level). This causes the issue.

> " Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'"

`if (health)`
The `()` for the `if` statement should be a condition (a question).

For example, doing `health < 0` is valid since its saying "Is health less than 0?"
Doing `health` is not, since its just saying "10" (or some number).

> "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or
>   indexer"

`(int)health = this;`
If you wanted to change the value of `health`, just do `health = 10`
 or `health = some_Variable_That_Is_An_Integer`